# RHEL 5.5 Yum Update Fails Dependency Error

Tags: linux, yum, rpm, redhat, update

I have 30 different RHEL 5.5 machines that will not update some 33 packages via Yum. Does anyone know why these packages will not install and how to correct this?

Yum clean all does not fix the issue, however skip broken will allow other updates to install but I am really after a way to clear this up for good.

They are stock boxes with RHEL subscription and not using any yum repositories other than Red Hat's own official repositories. They have not been updated for over a year!

```
yum update
Loaded plugins: rhnplugin, security
rhel-i386-client-5                                       | 1.4 kB     00:00     
rhel-i386-client-5/primary                               | 2.8 MB     00:09     
rhel-i386-client-5                                                    6607/6607
Skipping security plugin, no data
Setting up Update Process
Resolving Dependencies
Skipping security plugin, no data
--> Running transaction check
---> Package autofs.i386 1:5.0.1-0.rc2.143.el5_5.6 set to be updated
---> Package cpp.i386 0:4.1.2-48.el5 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: curl = 7.15.5-2.1.el5_3.5 for package: curl-devel
---> Package curl.i386 0:7.15.5-9.el5 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: cyrus-sasl-lib = 2.1.22-5.el5 for package: cyrus-sasl-devel
---> Package cyrus-sasl-lib.i386 0:2.1.22-5.el5_4.3 set to be updated
---> Package cyrus-sasl-md5.i386 0:2.1.22-5.el5_4.3 set to be updated
---> Package cyrus-sasl-plain.i386 0:2.1.22-5.el5_4.3 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: db4 = 4.3.29-10.el5 for package: db4-devel
---> Package db4.i386 0:4.3.29-10.el5_5.2 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: dbus = 1.1.2-12.el5 for package: dbus-devel
---> Package dbus.i386 0:1.1.2-14.el5 set to be updated
---> Package dbus-libs.i386 0:1.1.2-14.el5 set to be updated
---> Package dbus-x11.i386 0:1.1.2-14.el5 set to be updated
---> Package e2fsprogs.i386 0:1.39-23.el5_5.1 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: e2fsprogs-libs = 1.39-23.el5 for package: e2fsprogs-devel
---> Package e2fsprogs-libs.i386 0:1.39-23.el5_5.1 set to be updated
---> Package esc.i386 0:1.1.0-12.el5 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: expat = 1.95.8-8.2.1 for package: expat-devel
---> Package expat.i386 0:1.95.8-8.3.el5_5.3 set to be updated
---> Package firefox.i386 0:3.6.13-2.el5 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: freetype = 2.2.1-21.el5_3 for package: freetype-devel
---> Package freetype.i386 0:2.2.1-28.el5_5.1 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: gcc = 4.1.2-46.el5_4.1 for package: gcc-c++
--> Processing Dependency: gcc = 4.1.2-46.el5_4.1 for package: gcc-gfortran
---> Package gcc.i386 0:4.1.2-48.el5 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: gd = 2.0.33-9.4.el5_1.1 for package: gd-devel
---> Package gd.i386 0:2.0.33-9.4.el5_4.2 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: gnome-vfs2 = 2.16.2-4.el5 for package: gnome-vfs2-devel
---> Package gnome-vfs2.i386 0:2.16.2-6.el5_5.1 set to be updated
---> Package gnome-vfs2-smb.i386 0:2.16.2-6.el5_5.1 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: gnutls = 1.4.1-3.el5_3.5 for package: gnutls-devel
---> Package gnutls.i386 0:1.4.1-3.el5_4.8 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: gtk2 = 2.10.4-20.el5 for package: gtk2-devel
---> Package gtk2.i386 0:2.10.4-21.el5_5.6 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: hal = 0.5.8.1-52.el5 for package: hal-devel
---> Package hal.i386 0:0.5.8.1-59.el5 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: krb5-libs = 1.6.1-36.el5 for package: krb5-devel
---> Package krb5-libs.i386 0:1.6.1-36.el5_5.6 set to be updated
---> Package krb5-workstation.i386 0:1.6.1-36.el5_5.6 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libXi = 1.0.1-3.1 for package: libXi-devel
---> Package libXi.i386 0:1.0.1-4.el5_4 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libXrandr = 1.1.1-3.1 for package: libXrandr-devel
---> Package libXrandr.i386 0:1.1.1-3.3 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libXt = 1.0.2-3.1.fc6 for package: libXt-devel
---> Package libXt.i386 0:1.0.2-3.2.el5 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libgfortran = 4.1.2-46.el5_4.1 for package: gcc-gfortran
---> Package libgfortran.i386 0:4.1.2-48.el5 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libsepol = 1.15.2-2.el5 for package: libsepol-devel
---> Package libsepol.i386 0:1.15.2-3.el5 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++ = 4.1.2-46.el5_4.1 for package: gcc-c++
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++ = 4.1.2-46.el5_4.1 for package: libstdc++-devel
---> Package libstdc++.i386 0:4.1.2-48.el5 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: mesa-libGL = 6.5.1-7.7.el5 for package: mesa-libGL-devel
---> Package mesa-libGL.i386 0:6.5.1-7.8.el5 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: mesa-libGLU = 6.5.1-7.7.el5 for package: mesa-libGLU-devel
---> Package mesa-libGLU.i386 0:6.5.1-7.8.el5 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: newt = 0.52.2-12.el5_4.1 for package: newt-devel
---> Package newt.i386 0:0.52.2-15.el5 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: nspr = 4.7.6-1.el5_4 for package: nspr-devel
---> Package nspr.i386 0:4.8.6-1.el5 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: nss = 3.12.3.99.3-1.el5_3.2 for package: nss-devel
---> Package nss.i386 0:3.12.8-1.el5 set to be updated
---> Package nss-tools.i386 0:3.12.8-1.el5 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: openldap = 2.3.43-3.el5 for package: openldap-devel
---> Package openldap.i386 0:2.3.43-12.el5_5.3 set to be updated
---> Package openldap-clients.i386 0:2.3.43-12.el5_5.3 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: openssl = 0.9.8e-12.el5 for package: openssl-devel
---> Package openssl.i686 0:0.9.8e-12.el5_5.7 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: pam = 0.99.6.2-6.el5 for package: pam-devel
---> Package pam.i386 0:0.99.6.2-6.el5_5.2 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: popt = 1.10.2.3-18.el5 for package: rpm-devel
--> Processing Dependency: popt = 1.10.2.3-18.el5 for package: rpm-build
---> Package popt.i386 0:1.10.2.3-20.el5_5.1 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: python = 2.4.3-27.el5 for package: python-devel
---> Package python.i386 0:2.4.3-27.el5_5.3 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: rpm = 4.4.2.3-18.el5 for package: rpm-devel
--> Processing Dependency: rpm = 4.4.2.3-18.el5 for package: rpm-build
---> Package rpm.i386 0:4.4.2.3-20.el5_5.1 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: rpm-libs = 4.4.2.3-18.el5 for package: rpm-devel
--> Processing Dependency: rpm-libs = 4.4.2.3-18.el5 for package: rpm-build
---> Package rpm-libs.i386 0:4.4.2.3-20.el5_5.1 set to be updated
---> Package rpm-python.i386 0:4.4.2.3-20.el5_5.1 set to be updated
---> Package xulrunner.i386 0:1.9.2.13-3.el5 set to be updated
---> Package xulrunner-devel.i386 0:1.9.2.7-2.el5 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: xulrunner = 1.9.2.7-2.el5 for package: xulrunner-devel
--> Processing Dependency: nss-devel >= 3.12.6 for package: xulrunner-devel
--> Processing Dependency: nspr-devel >= 4.8 for package: xulrunner-devel
--> Processing Dependency: libnotify-devel for package: xulrunner-devel
---> Package yelp.i386 0:2.16.0-26.el5 set to be updated
rhel-i386-client-5/filelists                             |  16 MB     00:45     
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
xulrunner-devel-1.9.2.7-2.el5.i386 from rhel-i386-client-5 has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: libnotify-devel is needed by package xulrunner-devel-1.9.2.7-2.el5.i386 (rhel-i386-client-5)
mesa-libGLU-devel-6.5.1-7.7.el5.i386 from installed has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: mesa-libGLU = 6.5.1-7.7.el5 is needed by package mesa-libGLU-devel-6.5.1-7.7.el5.i386 (installed)
python-devel-2.4.3-27.el5.i386 from installed has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: python = 2.4.3-27.el5 is needed by package python-devel-2.4.3-27.el5.i386 (installed)
nss-devel-3.12.3.99.3-1.el5_3.2.i386 from installed has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: nss = 3.12.3.99.3-1.el5_3.2 is needed by package nss-devel-3.12.3.99.3-1.el5_3.2.i386 (installed)
libstdc++-devel-4.1.2-46.el5_4.1.i386 from installed has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: libstdc++ = 4.1.2-46.el5_4.1 is needed by package libstdc++-devel-4.1.2-46.el5_4.1.i386 (installed)
xulrunner-devel-1.9.2.7-2.el5.i386 from rhel-i386-client-5 has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: nspr-devel >= 4.8 is needed by package xulrunner-devel-1.9.2.7-2.el5.i386 (rhel-i386-client-5)
gcc-c++-4.1.2-46.el5_4.1.i386 from installed has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: libstdc++ = 4.1.2-46.el5_4.1 is needed by package gcc-c++-4.1.2-46.el5_4.1.i386 (installed)
rpm-devel-4.4.2.3-18.el5.i386 from installed has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: rpm-libs = 4.4.2.3-18.el5 is needed by package rpm-devel-4.4.2.3-18.el5.i386 (installed)
xulrunner-devel-1.9.2.7-2.el5.i386 from rhel-i386-client-5 has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: xulrunner = 1.9.2.7-2.el5 is needed by package xulrunner-devel-1.9.2.7-2.el5.i386 (rhel-i386-client-5)
nspr-devel-4.7.6-1.el5_4.i386 from installed has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: nspr = 4.7.6-1.el5_4 is needed by package nspr-devel-4.7.6-1.el5_4.i386 (installed)
libXrandr-devel-1.1.1-3.1.i386 from installed has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: libXrandr = 1.1.1-3.1 is needed by package libXrandr-devel-1.1.1-3.1.i386 (installed)
libsepol-devel-1.15.2-2.el5.i386 from installed has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: libsepol = 1.15.2-2.el5 is needed by package libsepol-devel-1.15.2-2.el5.i386 (installed)
libXt-devel-1.0.2-3.1.fc6.i386 from installed has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: libXt = 1.0.2-3.1.fc6 is needed by package libXt-devel-1.0.2-3.1.fc6.i386 (installed)
mesa-libGL-devel-6.5.1-7.7.el5.i386 from installed has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: mesa-libGL = 6.5.1-7.7.el5 is needed by package mesa-libGL-devel-6.5.1-7.7.el5.i386 (installed)
openldap-devel-2.3.43-3.el5.i386 from installed has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: openldap = 2.3.43-3.el5 is needed by package openldap-devel-2.3.43-3.el5.i386 (installed)
openssl-devel-0.9.8e-12.el5.i386 from installed has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: openssl = 0.9.8e-12.el5 is needed by package openssl-devel-0.9.8e-12.el5.i386 (installed)
dbus-devel-1.1.2-12.el5.i386 from installed has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: dbus = 1.1.2-12.el5 is needed by package dbus-devel-1.1.2-12.el5.i386 (installed)
newt-devel-0.52.2-12.el5_4.1.i386 from installed has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: newt = 0.52.2-12.el5_4.1 is needed by package newt-devel-0.52.2-12.el5_4.1.i386 (installed)
gnome-vfs2-devel-2.16.2-4.el5.i386 from installed has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: gnome-vfs2 = 2.16.2-4.el5 is needed by package gnome-vfs2-devel-2.16.2-4.el5.i386 (installed)
gnutls-devel-1.4.1-3.el5_3.5.i386 from installed has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: gnutls = 1.4.1-3.el5_3.5 is needed by package gnutls-devel-1.4.1-3.el5_3.5.i386 (installed)
rpm-build-4.4.2.3-18.el5.i386 from installed has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: rpm-libs = 4.4.2.3-18.el5 is needed by package rpm-build-4.4.2.3-18.el5.i386 (installed)
gd-devel-2.0.33-9.4.el5_1.1.i386 from installed has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: gd = 2.0.33-9.4.el5_1.1 is needed by package gd-devel-2.0.33-9.4.el5_1.1.i386 (installed)
e2fsprogs-devel-1.39-23.el5.i386 from installed has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: e2fsprogs-libs = 1.39-23.el5 is needed by package e2fsprogs-devel-1.39-23.el5.i386 (installed)
xulrunner-devel-1.9.2.7-2.el5.i386 from rhel-i386-client-5 has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: nss-devel >= 3.12.6 is needed by package xulrunner-devel-1.9.2.7-2.el5.i386 (rhel-i386-client-5)
krb5-devel-1.6.1-36.el5.i386 from installed has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: krb5-libs = 1.6.1-36.el5 is needed by package krb5-devel-1.6.1-36.el5.i386 (installed)
gcc-gfortran-4.1.2-46.el5_4.1.i386 from installed has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: libgfortran = 4.1.2-46.el5_4.1 is needed by package gcc-gfortran-4.1.2-46.el5_4.1.i386 (installed)
curl-devel-7.15.5-2.1.el5_3.5.i386 from installed has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: curl = 7.15.5-2.1.el5_3.5 is needed by package curl-devel-7.15.5-2.1.el5_3.5.i386 (installed)
pam-devel-0.99.6.2-6.el5.i386 from installed has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: pam = 0.99.6.2-6.el5 is needed by package pam-devel-0.99.6.2-6.el5.i386 (installed)
rpm-build-4.4.2.3-18.el5.i386 from installed has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: rpm = 4.4.2.3-18.el5 is needed by package rpm-build-4.4.2.3-18.el5.i386 (installed)
expat-devel-1.95.8-8.2.1.i386 from installed has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: expat = 1.95.8-8.2.1 is needed by package expat-devel-1.95.8-8.2.1.i386 (installed)
gcc-c++-4.1.2-46.el5_4.1.i386 from installed has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: gcc = 4.1.2-46.el5_4.1 is needed by package gcc-c++-4.1.2-46.el5_4.1.i386 (installed)
gtk2-devel-2.10.4-20.el5.i386 from installed has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: gtk2 = 2.10.4-20.el5 is needed by package gtk2-devel-2.10.4-20.el5.i386 (installed)
gcc-gfortran-4.1.2-46.el5_4.1.i386 from installed has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: gcc = 4.1.2-46.el5_4.1 is needed by package gcc-gfortran-4.1.2-46.el5_4.1.i386 (installed)
cyrus-sasl-devel-2.1.22-5.el5.i386 from installed has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: cyrus-sasl-lib = 2.1.22-5.el5 is needed by package cyrus-sasl-devel-2.1.22-5.el5.i386 (installed)
rpm-devel-4.4.2.3-18.el5.i386 from installed has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: popt = 1.10.2.3-18.el5 is needed by package rpm-devel-4.4.2.3-18.el5.i386 (installed)
db4-devel-4.3.29-10.el5.i386 from installed has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: db4 = 4.3.29-10.el5 is needed by package db4-devel-4.3.29-10.el5.i386 (installed)
rpm-build-4.4.2.3-18.el5.i386 from installed has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: popt = 1.10.2.3-18.el5 is needed by package rpm-build-4.4.2.3-18.el5.i386 (installed)
rpm-devel-4.4.2.3-18.el5.i386 from installed has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: rpm = 4.4.2.3-18.el5 is needed by package rpm-devel-4.4.2.3-18.el5.i386 (installed)
libXi-devel-1.0.1-3.1.i386 from installed has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: libXi = 1.0.1-3.1 is needed by package libXi-devel-1.0.1-3.1.i386 (installed)
hal-devel-0.5.8.1-52.el5.i386 from installed has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: hal = 0.5.8.1-52.el5 is needed by package hal-devel-0.5.8.1-52.el5.i386 (installed)
freetype-devel-2.2.1-21.el5_3.i386 from installed has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: freetype = 2.2.1-21.el5_3 is needed by package freetype-devel-2.2.1-21.el5_3.i386 (installed)
Error: Missing Dependency: libgfortran = 4.1.2-46.el5_4.1 is needed by package gcc-gfortran-4.1.2-46.el5_4.1.i386 (installed)
Error: Missing Dependency: libsepol = 1.15.2-2.el5 is needed by package libsepol-devel-1.15.2-2.el5.i386 (installed)
Error: Missing Dependency: libstdc++ = 4.1.2-46.el5_4.1 is needed by package gcc-c++-4.1.2-46.el5_4.1.i386 (installed)
Error: Missing Dependency: mesa-libGL = 6.5.1-7.7.el5 is needed by package mesa-libGL-devel-6.5.1-7.7.el5.i386 (installed)
Error: Missing Dependency: mesa-libGLU = 6.5.1-7.7.el5 is needed by package mesa-libGLU-devel-6.5.1-7.7.el5.i386 (installed)
Error: Missing Dependency: freetype = 2.2.1-21.el5_3 is needed by package freetype-devel-2.2.1-21.el5_3.i386 (installed)
Error: Missing Dependency: hal = 0.5.8.1-52.el5 is needed by package hal-devel-0.5.8.1-52.el5.i386 (installed)
Error: Missing Dependency: libXt = 1.0.2-3.1.fc6 is needed by package libXt-devel-1.0.2-3.1.fc6.i386 (installed)
Error: Missing Dependency: openldap = 2.3.43-3.el5 is needed by package openldap-devel-2.3.43-3.el5.i386 (installed)
Error: Missing Dependency: libstdc++ = 4.1.2-46.el5_4.1 is needed by package libstdc++-devel-4.1.2-46.el5_4.1.i386 (installed)
Error: Missing Dependency: nss-devel >= 3.12.6 is needed by package xulrunner-devel-1.9.2.7-2.el5.i386 (rhel-i386-client-5)
Error: Missing Dependency: newt = 0.52.2-12.el5_4.1 is needed by package newt-devel-0.52.2-12.el5_4.1.i386 (installed)
Error: Missing Dependency: gnutls = 1.4.1-3.el5_3.5 is needed by package gnutls-devel-1.4.1-3.el5_3.5.i386 (installed)
Error: Missing Dependency: gnome-vfs2 = 2.16.2-4.el5 is needed by package gnome-vfs2-devel-2.16.2-4.el5.i386 (installed)
Error: Missing Dependency: libXrandr = 1.1.1-3.1 is needed by package libXrandr-devel-1.1.1-3.1.i386 (installed)
Error: Missing Dependency: python = 2.4.3-27.el5 is needed by package python-devel-2.4.3-27.el5.i386 (installed)
Error: Missing Dependency: gcc = 4.1.2-46.el5_4.1 is needed by package gcc-c++-4.1.2-46.el5_4.1.i386 (installed)
Error: Missing Dependency: libnotify-devel is needed by package xulrunner-devel-1.9.2.7-2.el5.i386 (rhel-i386-client-5)
Error: Missing Dependency: popt = 1.10.2.3-18.el5 is needed by package rpm-devel-4.4.2.3-18.el5.i386 (installed)
Error: Missing Dependency: openssl = 0.9.8e-12.el5 is needed by package openssl-devel-0.9.8e-12.el5.i386 (installed)
Error: Missing Dependency: curl = 7.15.5-2.1.el5_3.5 is needed by package curl-devel-7.15.5-2.1.el5_3.5.i386 (installed)
Error: Missing Dependency: xulrunner = 1.9.2.7-2.el5 is needed by package xulrunner-devel-1.9.2.7-2.el5.i386 (rhel-i386-client-5)
Error: Missing Dependency: nspr = 4.7.6-1.el5_4 is needed by package nspr-devel-4.7.6-1.el5_4.i386 (installed)
Error: Missing Dependency: nss = 3.12.3.99.3-1.el5_3.2 is needed by package nss-devel-3.12.3.99.3-1.el5_3.2.i386 (installed)
Error: Missing Dependency: popt = 1.10.2.3-18.el5 is needed by package rpm-build-4.4.2.3-18.el5.i386 (installed)
Error: Missing Dependency: libXi = 1.0.1-3.1 is needed by package libXi-devel-1.0.1-3.1.i386 (installed)
Error: Missing Dependency: nspr-devel >= 4.8 is needed by package xulrunner-devel-1.9.2.7-2.el5.i386 (rhel-i386-client-5)
Error: Missing Dependency: pam = 0.99.6.2-6.el5 is needed by package pam-devel-0.99.6.2-6.el5.i386 (installed)
Error: Missing Dependency: rpm = 4.4.2.3-18.el5 is needed by package rpm-build-4.4.2.3-18.el5.i386 (installed)
Error: Missing Dependency: cyrus-sasl-lib = 2.1.22-5.el5 is needed by package cyrus-sasl-devel-2.1.22-5.el5.i386 (installed)
Error: Missing Dependency: gtk2 = 2.10.4-20.el5 is needed by package gtk2-devel-2.10.4-20.el5.i386 (installed)
Error: Missing Dependency: dbus = 1.1.2-12.el5 is needed by package dbus-devel-1.1.2-12.el5.i386 (installed)
Error: Missing Dependency: db4 = 4.3.29-10.el5 is needed by package db4-devel-4.3.29-10.el5.i386 (installed)
Error: Missing Dependency: rpm-libs = 4.4.2.3-18.el5 is needed by package rpm-build-4.4.2.3-18.el5.i386 (installed)
Error: Missing Dependency: gcc = 4.1.2-46.el5_4.1 is needed by package gcc-gfortran-4.1.2-46.el5_4.1.i386 (installed)
Error: Missing Dependency: expat = 1.95.8-8.2.1 is needed by package expat-devel-1.95.8-8.2.1.i386 (installed)
Error: Missing Dependency: gd = 2.0.33-9.4.el5_1.1 is needed by package gd-devel-2.0.33-9.4.el5_1.1.i386 (installed)
Error: Missing Dependency: krb5-libs = 1.6.1-36.el5 is needed by package krb5-devel-1.6.1-36.el5.i386 (installed)
Error: Missing Dependency: rpm = 4.4.2.3-18.el5 is needed by package rpm-devel-4.4.2.3-18.el5.i386 (installed)
Error: Missing Dependency: rpm-libs = 4.4.2.3-18.el5 is needed by package rpm-devel-4.4.2.3-18.el5.i386 (installed)
Error: Missing Dependency: e2fsprogs-libs = 1.39-23.el5 is needed by package e2fsprogs-devel-1.39-23.el5.i386 (installed)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: package-cleanup --problems
                        package-cleanup --dupes
                        rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

The repolist is

```
yum repolist all
Loaded plugins: rhnplugin, security
repo id             repo name                                     status
rhel-debuginfo      Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5Client - i386 - Deb disabled
rhel-debuginfo-beta Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5Client Beta - i386  disabled
rhel-i386-client-5  Red Hat Enterprise Linux Desktop (v. 5 for 32 enabled: 6,607
repolist: 6,607
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly you do not have the subchannel with the devel versions enabled. See [In RHEL 5, yum cannot find a package (python-devel)](https://serverfault.com/questions/61853/in-rhel-5-yum-cannot-find-a-package-python-devel)

Comment: Yes it could be this! I'm confused as to why the workstations would need these devel packages though?

Comment: The RPM's installed on these machines come from a number of different sources and it looks like it will be easier to reinstall than unpick the dependency errors.

Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Longshot here.. but do you have something like

```
exclude=*-devel
```

in your /etc/yum.conf

Comment: no there is no mention of exclude= in yum.conf at all